# How do you conceptually add floating point/decimal numbers in assembly?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, addition

In my assembly class (MIPS), I'm presented with the question:

> Add 2.85x10^3 to 7.88x10^4 using the following assumptions:
>   Assume that you have only 3 sig figs, with guard (2 digits) and round digits.
>   Assume that you have only 3 sig figs, without guard and round digits.

I'm a bit confused on how guard effects the outcome of adding numbers. Could someone explain to me the process for adding floating point/decimal numbers and what effect guard has?

Comment: Find the common exponent, scale, add the mantissas.

Comment: do you understand how to do the math (it is actually just simple grade school stuff once you see it) or is it that you dont know how to implement that math in asm?

Comment: I understand scientific notation - I can easily add the two numbers in base 10. It's the conversion to binary/asm I am unclear on...